# What Lego set would this building belong to? grays and red flags of different sizes

Tags: set-identification

What Lego set would this building belong to?

I cannot find the logo on the flag.

[image: grays and red flags of different sizes]

Answer (score 4):

I searched BrickLink for <kbd>2335p*</kbd> and then restricted the color to <kbd>Red</kbd>.

According to BrickLink, the only set with [2335pb013 Flag 2 x 2 Square with Avatar Fire Nation Black Lines and Fancy Scroll Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2335pb013#T=C&C=5) is [3829 Fire Nation Ship](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3829-1)

[image: 2335pb013 Flag 2 x 2 Square with Avatar Fire Nation Black Lines and Fancy Scroll Pattern]

[image: 3829 Fire Nation Ship]